# hide incoming querystring with htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want that anybody who comes to my site

```
site.com?affiliate=a12b345c67
```

hides the affiliate querystring completely

I'm sure it's something like this, but nothing happens

```
RewriteRule ^/?affiliate= / [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you cannot hide this.. atleast, it won't work anymore if you hide it.

Comment: right so it's a php redirect then, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To strip `affiliate=` query string from your URLs, place this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^affiliate=[^&]+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [L,R=301,NE]
```

Answer (score -2):

First of all you need to charge the URL from which users are coming to your website. Change it to:

```
site.com?/a12b345c67/
```

.htaccess cant change your URL structure on the fly.

Let me know if its ok.

Regards.

Answer (score -2):

you could save the incoming $_GET parameter(if exists) to a session(or cookie, or whatever persistent storage) and reload the page.

```
   session_start();
   if(isset($_GET['affiliate']){
       $_SESSION['affiliate'] = $_GET['affiliate'];
       header('location: site.com');
   }
```

you could then use the affiliate token from the session,cookie or whatever persistent storage